# Unable to type text into a WPF textbox when Alt is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, input, textbox, keyboard

In WPF, I have a window with textboxes.  When I click in a textbox, hold the Alt key, and type text, nothing happens.  I want to be able to type text into the textbox with Alt held in the same way I'd be able to as if Alt wasn't being held.  I tried putting a KeyDown handler method on the window and setting e.Handled = true, but that didn't work.  Here's what I tried:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key == Key.System && e.OriginalSource is TextBox)
     {
          e.Handled = true;
     }
}
```

I tried putting the handler on the textboxes instead of the window as well, and I also tried using the PreviewKeyDown handler instead of KeyDown.  The e.Handled = true; line is being reached, but it's not doing anything.

Comment: I don't know any place in windows where thats possible, it could be something native within windows kernel assuiming a keyboard shortcut and therefore not invoking any keyboad events. Why do you need to type while holding alt?

Comment: AFAIK you can't with the `ALT` (it enables the AccessKey), when the key is down it blocks.